# How go to servlet from jsp which included in folder

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, post, web.xml

I have a problem and can't find information.

I run my web-app from jsp-page which find on folder in "web". And try to go to servlet 
Smth like this

```
<form action="MyServlet" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="command" />
</form>
```

In web.xml next

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>mypackage.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I thought that this should work but when I run my app I see next url for button 
[image: example]

But my goal is get url localhost:8080/TomcatApp/MyServlet

I try to do it using GlassFish and Apache Tomcat 7. I don't know. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form's action is relative to the current page's path.  So if your JSP is at `/TomcatApp/folder/some-page.jsp`, just setting the action to `MyServlet` is the same as `/TomcatApp/folder/MyServlet` because it automatically uses the current path as a base.  To get just `/TomcatApp/MyServlet`, you need to set your form's action to either `../MyServlet` or `${request.contextPath}/MyServlet`.